# Где хранятся данные бд Redis, в оперативной или в постоянной памяти?

Tags: база-данных, redis

Где хранятся данные бд Redis, в оперативной или в постоянной памяти?

Comment: Как настроите — так и будет. Redis умеет периодически сохранять данные из памяти на диск, а при перезапуске считывать с диска

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все данные Redis хранятся в памяти, что обеспечивает низкую задержку и высокую пропускную способность доступа к данным. В отличие от традиционных баз данных, хранилища данных в памяти не требуют перемещения на диск, что сокращает задержку ядра до микросекунд.